# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size()

Tags: php

I am uploading my website on to a server, and it uploaded successfully. After that, when I run, it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size().

I also check my [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) version on my server is 5.3.14. I couldn't figure out how I can deal with this. I used this function for query string encryption. I searched about this on Google and some people say you have to ask your host to install it. Is there another way to install this or alternate function that work just like this mcrypt_get_block_size()?

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to install and enable [mcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mcrypt).

On a [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) based Linux distribution (like [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)), run this from command line:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Comment: This command is for debian based linux distribution. What is your server OS?

Comment: And if this doesn't help? If mcrypt installed, enabled, but this function still undefined?

Answer (score 7):

As Alex said, you need to install the library, but don't forget to enable it.

```
  sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
  sudo php5enmod mcrypt
  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```